# Re-labelling graph columns in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to change the names of the column labels on the x axis of a boxplot. 
This is my code for the graph:

```
boxplot(datab~area,ylab="Heather Cover (%)",xlab="Survey Area")
axis(1, at=1:3, lab=c("Hangars", "East", "Runway"))
```

This works, however, the old column names (1,2,3) remain underneath the new labels. How do I get rid of these?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is remove the x-axis labels using xaxt="n" in the original plot. Let me illustrate using the "mtcar" data.

```
boxplot(mpg~gear, data=mtcars, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:3, lab=c("Hangars", "East", "Runway"))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've been looking for a solution for hours. You're a star!!